# How to extract column value within square brackets in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe something like this

```
+---+---------+--------------------+
| id|     name|               actor|
+---+---------+--------------------+
|  0|    [123]|                 tom|
|  1|    [321]|                brad|
+---+---------+--------------------+
```

FYI. 'name' - StringType()

But I would like to get something like this

```
+---+---------+--------------------+
| id|     name|               actor|
+---+---------+--------------------+
|  0|      123|                 tom|
|  1|      321|                brad|
+---+---------+--------------------+
```

I am trying to extract the values between the square bracket and cast it to IntegerType. I tried using **split** function with regular expression. But, its not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) to deconstruct arrays:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)

columns = ['id', 'name', 'actor']
data = [(0, [123], 'tom'), (1, [321], 'brad')]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

exploded = df.withColumn('name', F.explode('name'))
exploded.show()

+---+----+-----+
| id|name|actor|
+---+----+-----+
|  0| 123|  tom|
|  1| 321| brad|
+---+----+-----+
```

By checking the types, you can see that it is actually the contained type:

```
exploded.dtypes

[('id', 'bigint'), ('name', 'bigint'), ('actor', 'string')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the following. If **df** is your given dataframe name

```
df.select(df.name.cast("string").alias('name')).collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this, 
Please make sure that I am not changing the schema for final DF and so it will still act as string. if you want. you will have to change the `schema`.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StringType, StructField

data=sc.parallelize([
    [0, [123], "tom"],
    [1, [123], "brad"]
])


schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("count", StringType(), True)
    ])
DF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, schema)
DF.show()
+---+-----+-----+
| id| name|count|
+---+-----+-----+
|  0|[123]|  tom|
|  1|[123]| brad|
+---+-----+-----+

x = data.map(lambda x: [x[0],int(x[1][0]), x[2]]).toDF(schema)
x.show()
+---+----+-----+
| id|name|count|
+---+----+-----+
|  0| 123|  tom|
|  1| 123| brad|
+---+----+-----+
```